# Path Unseen after Updating Angular 2 Version

Tags: angular

I updated my angular/cli to 2.3 recently but and i have realized that it is unable to load my paths. However, When i was having an angular cli version 2.1, The application was loading the path accurately with no issues but after the update, none of the paths specified in my application is able to load. Below, my bootsrap.min.css and the others which used to load in my previous angular cli version doesn't load anymore in the current updated cli version, 2.3 .Anyone has an idea of why this is happening? I have been stuck at this for 3 days now.

**Error Encountered**

```
     http://localhost:4200/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)

        Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css undefined

    ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
        at resolvePromis…, rejection: "Failed to load ../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask}

 http://localhost:4200/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:4200/css/local.css 404 (Not Found)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.54",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: bootstrap and font-awesome are not even listed in your package.json. Also, the latest angular cli version is v1.0.0-rc.0. You seem to confuse angular, the framework, with angular-cli, the tool used to build angular applications.

Comment: @JBNizet I am new to this :). With the previous version i was using, bootstrap and font-awesome was not listed in my pacckage.json but it was working. However, how do i overcome this please?

Comment: Install bootstrap and font-awesome with npm, then add `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"` to the `styles` attribute in the .angular-cli.json.

Comment: @JBNizet, i have added the paths to the styles attribute but it is still raising the same error in the console.

Comment: You don't need any reference to bootstrap and font-awesome in your index.html (assuming you have those). They should be bundled by angular-cli in the bundles it generates.

Comment: Anyone willing to help with another best solution please?